# Rosjava subscriber doesn't get any data

Tags: ros, linux, ros-kinetic, network, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a rosbag as a topic publisher to receive the data on my phone and update the info I have on my app.
I've been looking around and I think the main issue is this console output:

```
E/UpdatePublisherRunnable: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "mypcname": No address associated with hostname
```

Im playing a rosbag from my pc and made sure the topic is working.
I used the debug of android studio and the subscriber gets setted properly, but when I should receive the message the onNewMessage never triggers.
I have setted up the ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME correctly on my pc.

Not sure what to do to solve this and couldn't find a proper answer anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327528/rosjava-subscriber-doesn%27t-get-any-data/) by [luischd](https://answers.ros.org/users/38562/luischd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tav_PG](https://answers.ros.org/users/43825/tav_pg/) on 2019-07-02**:
I do not have a solution but have you...

[1] ..run a 'IsPortOpen' before the error exception.
[2] ...called addMessageListener(MessageListener<T!> { ...   prior to onNewMessage ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-04**:
Please post your `EDIT` as an answer and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [luischd](https://answers.ros.org/users/38562/luischd/) on 2019-07-04**:
I can't accept my own answer, a pop-up says 10 points are required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED:

My code was all good and the network configuration before roscore too. The only problem was that I didn't know you had to set up the ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME on every console you are using for Ros.
I was playing the rosbag on a different console (not on the roscore one) and the subscriber was publishing on localhost -> mypcname, which is the default value.
To see if you have setted up your network values try echo $ROS_MASTER_URI.

---

Originally posted by [luischd](https://answers.ros.org/users/38562/luischd/) with karma: 18 on 2019-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0